# Getting iPhone notifications to call my delegate when the application is running in the background

Tags: ios4, background, uialertview, uilocalnotification

I have an enterprise application that I want to keep running, so it can call a webservice and inform the user when there is something they need to do.

So, it now runs in the background, it makes the calls, gets results, but informing the user is my problem.

When I fire off a `UILocalNotification` the alert doesn't call my `UIAlertDelegate`, and I don't see how to set that alert to do that.

Here is my code for how I am doing the notification, and this actually brings up an alert, but I need it to then bring up a `View` so they can see the table, but the `View` it opens isn't one of the two my application uses.

```
        UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        if (localNotif) {
            localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%@ has a message for you.", nil), @"FYR"];
            localNotif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"Read Msg", nil);
            localNotif.soundName = nil;             
            localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1;
            NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Your Background Task works", ItemListKey, @"Message from FYR", MessageTitleKey, nil];
            localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotif];
            [localNotif release];
        }
```

Also, so I tried to have an alert come up that I can set the delegate, so in my controller, where I call the above code I am also calling this:

```
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]  
         postNotificationName:@"ShowAlert"
         object:nil
         userInfo:mydata];
```

This notification is then picked up and eventually this function is called, and this does work, but the alert isn't visible to the user, I expect because it is in the background.

```
- (void) _showAlert:(NSString*)pushmessage withTitle:(NSString*)title {
    NSLog(@"%@", @"Attemping to show alert");
    UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title 
                                                        message:pushmessage
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",nil];
    [alertView show];
    if (alertView) {
        [alertView release];
    }
}
```

In the main delegate, I have this defined, and the appropriate functions:

`@interface FYRViewAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate> {`

my thought being that if I can get the alert that pops up to call this delegate then it can execute this code:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertview clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    alertview--;
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    } else {
        [self.window addSubview:[tableController view]];
    }
}
```

So, is there any way to get the `UILocalNotification` to use my delegate for the alert?

Or, is there a way to have an alert show up when the application is in the background?

Or, do I need to write two applications, so they communicate with remote notifications, so when the application is in the background one runs and then starts up the main application with a remote notification.  I don't like this approach as it seems very messy, but would probably work.

Since the program never stops running

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {`

is only called at startup, the local notification never calls it and this also is never called:

`- (void) application:(UIApplication*)application
didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)localNotification {`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you don't post notifications when the application is active. Couldn't you simply set a flag when you post a local notification and then check the flag when the application becomes active:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if (localNotificationPosted) {
        // Do whatever you need to do.
    }
}
```

This will likely be the correct behavior, since the application will become active unless the user dismisses the notification. Even if the user dismisses the notification, showing new messages the next time the app is opened probably isn't a bad thing.

Comment: When the application is in the foreground I just update the table.  Ideally I want them to not think about the application unless something comes up that needs their attention, so, it could be weeks (for some people) before anything needs their attention, and for others it may be just minutes.  Requiring the user to open the application to see what needs their attention takes away from what convenience the program could be, but, your solution may be the best approach on the iPhone.

Comment: Another issue is that the application doesn't really go to sleep, it stays active, so I don't know if it will ever call "applicationDidBecomeActive", and I am not certain how to work around that.  The other solution is to just go to sleep when not active, and then when they open it, call the webservice and update at that point, but, again, that just seems like a bad design.